# Polar group strong dipole effect molecular axis

Tags: organic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, molecules

There are some fundamental charactaristics of liquid crystal. One of them is that all liquid crystals are organic compounds and at one side of their long molecular foundation there exists a polar group such as -CN, -NO2, -NH2, -OR etc.

A strong dipole effect in molecules is created by the existance of polar group; so the molecular axies are parallel.

Actually I don't understand the characteristic perfectly because of having confusion at several terms.

My questions are :

1. What are the polar polar groups?
2. What is the strong dipole effect?
3. What is molecular axis?

I especially want to know  about molecular axis with an extant explanation.

Comment: Could you perhaps include the source of where you got this?

Comment: Molecular axis is the 'long direction' for a molecule that is roughly cylindrical or rectangular flat.  the rest of the terms you explained in your question.